# How does Grails support HTML5 Offline Mode?

Tags: html, grails, offline-caching

I am writing a Grails/GSP app that needs to be functional offline when no network is present. I read the following articles on HTML5 Offline/AppCache which were very informative:

- [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/offline); and
- [Dive into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html)

To summarize (`tl;dr`), I will need to define a `manifest` attribute in each page's `<html>` element like so:

```
<html manifest="myapp-cache.manifest">
    ...
</html>
```

Where `myapp-cache.manifest` is the name of a "cache manifest" file that specifies offline/caching behaviors and might look like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
NETWORK:
    *
CACHE:
index.html
somethingCool.html
myimage.png
myapp.css
```

The problem here is that, with Grails, **I will have no HTML files to cache.** In reality, I might have an `index.gsp` and `somethingCool.gsp`, but they represent pre-processed HTML and will never exist as HTML documents. And I can't specify GSPs in the cache manifest, because GSPs are (and shouldn't be) directly fetchable from the client-side.

Things get further complicated when we start reusing GSPs such as a `header.gsp` and `footer.gsp`, tag libs, and more.

So I ask: **does Grails support HTML5 Offline?** If so, how and in what capacity (where are the docs)? If not, is there anyway to coerce Grails to be Offline-compatible? Or is Grails incapable of this HTML5 feature?

---

#### Update

Perhaps this could be accomplished somehow via URL mapping? For instance, perhaps there's a way to get Grails to map requests from, say, `http://myapp.example.com/fizzbuzz.html` to `http://myapp.example.com/fizzbuzz`, which would then prompt Grails to  invoke the right controller action, and render the correct GSP?

Comment: Can I assume this means that Grails doesn't support HTML5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement "I will have no HTML files to cache" is wrong. Grails is a server side framework, and though you work with GSPs, tag libs and so on on the server side, all your client (the browser) sees is pure HTML.

As such it should be perfectly fine to cache .gsp, as all the browser will get and cache is the HTML that Grails delivers. Don't get confused by the extension! When offline, the browser will take the HTML from the AppCache same way as it would .html.

AppCache is a client side technology, as such I doubt there is any specific documentation for server side technology in general and Grails in particular, as it works the same for any server side technology.

@sneeb Grails can deliver content in whatever format you wish, HTML, JSON, XML and so on. As such Grails supports any type of content, including HTML5.

Comment: Thanks @Michael B (+1) - but I think you are missing an important concept: one cannot request a GSP from the client-side. If I have a GSP called `fizzbuzz.gsp`, and I make a call to `http://myapp.example.com/fizzbuzz.gsp`, I will get an error. This is because, to the running app server, GSPs don't exist. Dynamically, on the fly, Grails converts URLs into HTML. To produce this HTML, it uses GSPs. But they are not a fetchable resource. This is why I don't believe Grails can support HTML5 Offline.

Comment: Offline requires you to specify the name of a file. On the server side, no such file exists (because there is no HTML file, and GSPs are not requestable).

Comment: Also @Michael B please see my update and my URL mapping idea. Is that plausible? If so, any ideas as to how I could implement? Thanks again!

Comment: Whatever URL you use from the client to fetch a page from the server, is the URL you have to put in your manifest in order to get it cached. All the client does when offline is looking into the appcache for the very same URL. So it should be perfectly fine to cache something like http://host/controller/action If it suits you better to use some extension in the URLs you can go and manage the URL mappings as you suggested (but IMHO is not really necessary).

Comment: Just so you know - AppCache has quite a few gotchas and might not be around forever. See http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag for some of the problems!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but thought I would mention: you don't need to include every html page in your cache manifest file, as long as each page includes the manifest attribute. When the browser sees the manifest attribute, it's smart enough to cache the current page as well as everything in the manifest file.

I've never tried it, but I believe this means you could include the manifest attribute in your main template, then every page that uses the main template would be cached along with the contents of the manifest file.